# VBA- Double click to add x to cell, but how to double click to remove?

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rInt As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("B3:CS71"))
    If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
        For Each rCell In rInt
            rCell.Value = "x"
        Next
    End If
    Set rInt = Nothing
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

I found a few example codes but they seem very customized to the situation and focused on values, which I couldn't get to operate, but just seeing if anyone else has seen "Double click to add x, double click to remove x", and how I could apply the "remove" part here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `If` statement inside your loop. Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim rInt As Range
  Dim rCell As Range

  Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("B3:CS71"))
  If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
      For Each rCell In rInt
          If rCell.Value = "" then
            rCell.Value = "x"
          Else
            rCell.Value = ""                
          End If
      Next
  End If
  Set rInt = Nothing
  Set rCell = Nothing
  Cancel = True
End Sub
```